# Proving $R^n$ is antisymmetric when R is antisymmetric

Tags: relations

Needing to solve this problem in a past paper. Not even sure where to start.

Let $R$ be a binary relation on some set S. Prove or disprove the following claim. "If $R$ is antisymmetric then $R^n$ is antisymmetric for every positive integer $n$".

Comment: What would the notation $R^n$ mean in the context of a relation?

Comment: @PyRulez It most likely means the $n$-fold composite relation: i.e. $R^2$ is the relation where $a R^2 c$ if and only if there exists $b$ such that $a R b$ and $b R c$.

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson Correct.

Comment: If you're "not even sure where to start", then start by writing down the definition of "antisymmetric relation" and "$R^n$".

Comment: Thanks everyone, think I have proven it below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$S=\{1,2,3,4\}$

$R = \{(1,3), (3,2), (2,4), (4,1)\}$

$R^2  = \{(1,2), (3,4), (2,1), (4,3)\}$

$R$ is antisymmetric, however $R^2$ is not antisymmetric, therefore disproven by counterexample.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Construct a counterexample for $n=2$; you can take $S$ to be a $4$-element set and $R$ to contain exactly $4$ ordered pairs.